# Magento 2: How to add a meta tag based on layout

Tags: magento2, layout, head

I have 3 main categories in my stores. In order to give them a general color theme, I created 3 layouts file in `app/design/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/page_layout`, they are named `category_white` , `category_black` , `category_blue`

Here is one of them (all 3 have same content actually)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
    <update handle="1column"/>

</layout>
```

This them gives me an additional class on my `<body>` and I use it in my CSS to give the proper colors.

When it comes to page building, my page configuration files always refer to `layout="1column"` then my 3 layouts inherit from it.

Now, I want as well to add the tag : `<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />` (with of course a different content for each of the 3 categories), but I understood that I can not do it directly from the layout files I have to do it from the page configuration files (i.e. not from page_layout folder but from layout folder).

How can I target only one layout, I tried to have my default.xml as below and it does not work.

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
...
</page>
<page layout="category_white" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
...
</page>
```

Comment: whether the issue is solved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add as in HTML:

your Layout would look like-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
  <head>
    <meta name="description" content=" "/>
  </head>
.......
.......
</layout>
```

Comment: Don't forget the last slash in the meta tag. It will break the page otherwise

Answer (score 2):

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="blockname">
        <action method="setText">
            <text>
                <![CDATA[<meta name="description" content=" "/>]]>
            </text>
        </action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Comment: I do not see here how to target the 3 different layouts...

Comment: meta tag is a head param,it is not targeted to specific layouts

Comment: Does not work when adding to `Layout Update XML` field on Magento 2.1.8

Comment: This is Magento 1 code, not Magento 2 code.